# Detecting when an object called is called by . accessor or as function call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I have the following object

```
let o = {
    fn:()=>1,
    a:2
}
```

if i say `o()` i want the call to be proxied to `fn` and if i say `o.a` the value of a should be returned, is it possible exactly as it is presented?

its more like having an unnamed default function for an object

Comment: Just let `o` be function itself: `let o = () => 1; o.a = 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since functions in JS are objects, you can extend them with properties:

```js
const o = Object.assign(() => o.fn(), {
  a: 5,
  fn: () => 1
});

console.log(o());
console.log(o.a);
```

If you need to overwrite non-writable Function properties, such as `name`, you can 1st create the function, and then use [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) to add properties, and change non-writables to writables.

Note: This feels hackish enough, without missing with the Function's non-writable properties. I recommend avoiding it.

```js
const o = () => o.fn();

Object.defineProperties(o, {
  fn: { value: () => 1 },
  a: { value: 5 },
  name: { writable: true, value: 'whatever' },
});

console.log(o());
console.log(o.a);
console.log(o.name);
```

Comment: it blows up when the object has a property named name! is there a magical way around this or i just need to avoid those prop names?!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible exactly as it is presented?

No, you can't because that's only a `key-value` object and not a function.

---

**You need to declare that object as a function:**

- Declare the function `fn` within the function `o`.
- Set an attribute called `a` to the current function `o`.

```js
let o = () => {
    fn = () => 1;
    o.a = 2;
    
    return fn();
};

console.log(o());
console.log(o.a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: functions _are_ objects and therefore can also have their own key-value properties...

Comment: @Alnitak yes, but in this case, it's only a `key-value` object and nothing else.

Comment: I was mostly trying to say that the relationship isn't transitive.  Functions are objects, but (most) objects are not functions.